# Finding processor id in which process is running [through command/interface similar to top]

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Is there any way i can get the CPU which CPU the process is running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `/proc/[id]/stat` file and read the 39th value (seperated by spaces).  This tells which cpu id the process of [pid] is currently running on:

```
cat /proc/[id]/stat | awk '{print $39}'
```

For more info: [`man proc`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc).

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna get it in code, it is the variable current points to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "ps" command as:

```
You can use "ps" command as:

ps -p <pid> -o pid,comm,psr
Ex:
ps -p 1 -o pid,comm,psr
PID COMMAND         PSR
1   init              10
```